# Change the Grouping Sub Total row title into other name in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I can calculate the Sub total for each Item Type but the problem is intead of display "Total QTY:" , It only  displays the Item Type Name.
Please see my expected result:
[image]

And here is the query:

```
SELECT 
  [GOODS_TYPE] = COALESCE([_TYPE_NAME], 'GRAND_TOTAL'), 
    b.GOODS_CODE,b.GOODSNAME,a.CURRENCY,a.CUSTOMER_CD,  a.INVOICE_DATE,[QUANTITY] = SUM([QTY])
From [DVHead] a
    inner join [DVRecords] b
    on a.DELIVERYNO=b.DELIVERYNO                
        WHERE a.INVOICE_DATE='2018-05-04' 
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(([_TYPE_NAME],[GOODS_CODE],[GOODSNAME], 
        [CURRENCY],[CUSTOMER_CD],[INVOICE_DATE]),([_TYPE_NAME]),());
```

Comment: It shows that [_TYPE_NAME]  is not null, did you tried with some other column like b.GOODS_CODE which seems to be null

Comment: Yes, it is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CASE ... WHEN condition

```
[GOODS_TYPE] =  CASE WHEN   [_TYPE_NAME] IS NULL
                     THEN   'GRANT_TOTAL'
                     WHEN   [GOODS_CODE] IS NULL
                     THEN   'TOTAL ' + [_TYPE_NAME]
                     END
```